# Haskell Error how can I solve it

Tags: haskell

I get this error Message on my Haskell Codewhen compiling:

```
H5-1.hs:11:28: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
   |
11 |         show (Blattwert(a))= "show a"    |
```

Here is the original Code:

```
class ToDouble a 
 where toDouble :: a -> Double
```

How could I solve this issue?

```
data Op = Plus | Minus | Mal | Geteilt 
 deriving (Show, Eq)

data RechenBaum = BlattWert Double | AstOp RechenBaum Op RechenBaum 
 deriving Show

instance ToDouble (RechenBaum) where
    show (Blattwert(a))= "show a"
    toDouble(AstOp (Rechenbaum (a) Op(b) Rechenbaum(c)))= 
        ToDouble (AstOp (Rechenbaum (a) Op(Plus) Rechenbaum(c)))= RechenBaum(a)+ Rechenbaum(c)
        ToDouble (AstOp (Rechenbaum (a) Op(Minus) Rechenbaum(c)))= RechenBaum(a) -  Rechenbaum(c)
        ToDouble (AstOp (Rechenbaum (a) Op(Mal) Rechenbaum(c)))= RechenBaum(a)*Rechenbaum(c)
        ToDouble (AstOp (Rechenbaum (a) Op(Geteilt) Rechenbaum(c)))= RechenBaum(a) /Rechenbaum(c)
```

Comment: Where do you think the problem is? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Niclas! You appear to be a Haskell beginner. May I recommend reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) and learning more about Haskell before diving into these problems?

Comment: Hint: take a look at the brackets.

Comment: I can only recommend reading the book AJFarmar pointed out, it will save you a lot of time and trouble.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues, but the compiler is currently complaining about your attempt to define `show`:

```
instance ToDouble (RechenBaum) where
    show (Blattwert(a))= "show a"
```

1. The function `show` is not a member of the class `ToDouble` so you can not define it in the where block for a `ToDouble` instance.
2. You are using some odd syntax for pattern matching.  Don't `Rechenbaum(a)` but instead `(Rechenbaum a)`.  EDIT: Rechenbaum isn't even a constructor so don't use it as such. If you want a variable that matches any constructor use `a` or pattern match with one of the constructors.  Same goes for your uses of `Op` which is not a constructor.
3. There is no data constructor named `ToDouble` so your definition of `toDouble` inside the instance makes no sense at all.
4. The constructor `RechenBaum` will produce a value of type `RechenBaum` and not a `Double` so using it on the right hand side of `toDouble` doesn't make much sense.  Actually, now that I look there are no `RechenBaum` constructors so using it as such is itself an error - the constructors for that type are namedd `BlattWert` and `AstOp`.
5. Sometimes you use `RechenBaum` and other times `Rechenbaum` - these are different symbols.